# Compilation error at an instance declaration, Haskell

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

I faced with strange compilation error.

```
import Foreign
import Foreign.C.Types
import Foreign.C.String

newtype Test = Test {testList :: [CShort]}   deriving (Show)    

instance Storable Test where
    sizeOf _ =  16
    peek _ = error "peek is not implemented"
    alignment _ = alignment (undefined :: CShort)
```

got

```
TestICH.hsc:9:16: parse error on input `='
```

`9:16` is `peek _ = er{here}ror "peek is not implemented"`, in the middle of the word `error`? How is it possible?

**Update**
Closed, trouble was with tabs

Comment: What version of GHC are you using?  I copy/pasted your code exactly and it compiled for me

Comment: GHCi, version 7.4.2 for Windows

Comment: I'm using 7.6.3, but there shouldn't be much difference between the two.  Is that the exact code you have in your file?  Try copy/pasting it back into your editor to see if maybe you had an indention problem or a typo you missed.

Comment: In particular, check your tabs vs spaces!

Comment: Yes, trouble were at "tabs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the indentation of the declarations of `sizeOf`, `peek` and `alignment`. They should all be indented to the same level. Most likely, one or more of the declarations is using tabs for indentation and the others are using spaces, which will cause this error. When writing Haskell, it is best to configure your editor to always use spaces instead of tabs to avoid this problem.